# No results for $in clause in mongodb with java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to fetch few records based on list of ids. I am getting the results if I run the query directly on robomongo. But, the same doesn't work at code level in java.

Sample record:

```
{
   "_id":"142",
   "projectId":"PR_811",
   "projectName":"ProjectTest007",
   "entityName":"id-1412516",
   "processName":"MSATesting",
   "startDate":{
      "$date":{
         "$numberLong":"1666051200000"
      }
   },
   "endDate":{
      "$date":{
         "$numberLong":"1666224000000"
      }
   },
   "isRegulated":"No",
   "tagNameList":[
      
   ],
   "projectRole":{
      "1464":"1464"
   },
   "projectPhase":{
      "634e611de8ba26418e93ac96":"634e611de8ba26418e93ac96"
   },
   "status":"Approved"
}


BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();  
query.put("_id", new BasicDBObject("$in", projectIds)); //ProjectIds has list of ids as strings
DBCollection dbCollection = database.getCollection("Projects"); 
DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find(query);
```

Not sure if I am missing something w.r.t in clause here.

Comment: Do you get results if you leave the `query` empty? (Helps check namespace issues and confirm that the problem is associated with the filter or not)

Comment: Yes, I do get results even if I switch from $in to $gt as a base for filter. For an instance, new BasicDBObject("$gt", '123') works perfectly

Comment: It just doesn't work with $in

Comment: The comment in the code snippet says that `ProjectIds has a list of ids`. Stored in what format, strings? Are the `_id` values in the documents ObjectIds or something else? Need to be sure that the data types match and there is too little information in the question to say anything definitively

Comment: Hi @user20042973 yes, _id has strings. I have updated the question. Please let me know if something else is needed.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong here. Assuming that `projectIds` is defined as an `ArrayList<String>` (which you haven't shared) and the entries match the values stored in the database I think it should work

Comment: It does match the ids. That's why I haven't shared it. I do get results if I query with similar list directly on robomongo

Answer (score 0):

some queries of robomongo vs our technical code method are different. For writing queries and searching in MongoDB check for $lookup command. Also you can just send id to model function and query it like collection.find(_id:id){ //results }

Comment: I guess lookup is for aggregate. I just need the list of records back from the matched list of ids.